# Using WIA to scan a doc, but the list doesn't show scanner's wirelessly connected to my network

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wia

```
private void show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    list1.Items.Clear();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count; i++) // Loop Through the get List Of Devices.
        {
            /*if (deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i].Type != WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType) // Skip device If it is not a scanner
            {
                continue;
            }*/
            list1.Items.Add(deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i].Properties["Name"].get_Value());
        }
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is the code to add the device to the list, and i have declared the device manager in the window_loaded as follows

```
WIA.DeviceManagerClass deviceManager = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();
```

Comment: Your code will only show the Network Card and not the IP of devices connected.  See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889483/How-to-List-all-devices-info-on-your-WLAN-router

Comment: i couldn't get it i want to show the device in the list and connect to it

Comment: Each GateWay has it own IP address so you really want to show the GateWay and the IP addresses connect to each GateWay.  Something like Netstat which you can run from cmd.exe > Netstat -a

Comment: i know the device ip and i also know the gateway ip, does that help i need an easy way .

Comment: What type of interface are the scanners using?  Ethernet, USB, Serial Port, BlueTooth? See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-startpage?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: wifi the device is connected wirelessly to my access point ,and i can print and scan normally in my desktop >

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the issue.  So you can see the device but not connect to the device?  So the issue is you can connect by name put not IP?  then the mask of the interface is wrong.  When connecting by name you are using a DNS server and when you connect by IP you are using IP routing which is using the mask of the interface.  Try using from cmd.exe >IPConfig/All

Comment: i can't see the device in the list nether connect to it > inside my C# application >

Comment: see the code i wrote adds to list1 items that are connected directly to usb port .... but not devices in my WLAN

Comment: sorry for making it hard to understand , iam new to stackoverflow and my english is not that good ,if there is another way like sending you photos of the problem !!

Comment: Do the device show when using NetStat?  The devices are IP addresses.  Use from cmd.exe >ARP -a to see IP addresses and the MAC.  The MAC contains the manufacture, model, and serial number.